# Imagick lost transparency when using setImageOpacity and composeImage

Tags: php, imagemagick, opacity, imagick, composite

I want to composite an image to another one with transparency. Therefore I use Imagick with PHP.

This is what I get: 
[image: imagick result]

This is what I want:
[image: expected result]

Does anyone has an answer, why the transparency of the $imageTransparent gets lost after using setImageOpacity()?

Here is my code:

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$imageTransparent = new \Imagick();

$background = new \ImagickPixel('rgba(0,0,255,1)');
$image->newImage(600, 400, $background);

$background = new \ImagickPixel('rgba(255,255,255,0)');
$imageTransparent->newImage(600, 400, $background);

$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ff0000');
$draw->polygon(array(
    array('x' => 50, 'y' => 50),
    array('x' => 400, 'y' => 50),
    array('x' => 50, 'y' => 300),
));

$imageTransparent->drawImage($draw);
$imageTransparent->setImageOpacity(0.5);

$image->compositeImage($imageTransparent, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
```

EDIT: I do not want to set the transparency in the DrawObject! $imageTransparency could be anything. e.g. a PNG with transparent background.

I want to to a dissolve: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#dissolve

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick command line if you want to decrease the transparency of an image by 50%, your would select the alpha channel and multiply it by 0.5, then turn all channels back on.

Here is a transparent Imagemagick logo (with white background made transparent).

[image]

```
convert \
\( -size 600x400 xc:blue \) \
\( logot.png -channel a -evaluate multiply 0.5 +channel \) \
-composite test2.png
```

[image]

As compared to not changing the alpha channel and just composting as:

```
convert \
\( -size 600x400 xc:blue \) \
\( logot.png \) \
-composite test1.png
```

[image]

Sorry I do not know the equivalent commands in Imagick. But see Imagick::evaluateImage

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Imagick that well, but try using an opaque blue background on your transparent image and then draw a half transparent red triangle on it. (You were setting the whole output image to half transparency and using a transparent white background on the smaller image). Note I have removed your line `$imageTransparent->setImageOpacity(0.5);`

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$imageTransparent = new \Imagick();

$background = new \ImagickPixel('rgba(0,0,255,1)');
$image->newImage(600, 400, $background);

$background = new \ImagickPixel('rgba(0,0,255,1)');
$imageTransparent->newImage(600, 400, $background);

$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');
$draw->polygon(array(
    array('x' => 50, 'y' => 50),
    array('x' => 400, 'y' => 50),
    array('x' => 50, 'y' => 300),
));

$imageTransparent->drawImage($draw);

$image->compositeImage($imageTransparent, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
```

The above should be the equivalent of the following Imagemagick command line:

```
convert \
\( -size 600x400 xc:blue \) \
\( -size 600x400 xc:blue -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" \
     -draw "polygon 50,50 400,50 50,300" \) \
-composite test.png
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I want: $draw->setFillColor('rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');

Lets say $imageTransparent is a image loaded from PNG ;)